# Is it possible to calculate limit points?

Tags: matlab, math

Suppose I have a function `fun=@(x)(1-exp(-x))./x`. What I want to compute is `fun([0,1])`. It can be computed that when `x->0`, `fun->1`. However, if I simply type `fun([0,1])`, the first element is NaN. Is it possible to have a command so that `fun(0)` gives `1`?

Comment: You might want to edit the title a bit; your previous one was about as clear as mud, so I changed it to something (close to) what you are mathematically doing. If it is wrong now, apologies.

Comment: `fun(eps)` returns `1` so you could use that to get limits around any real number but I have no idea how to do it for `Inf` and `-Inf`, you can define an anonymous function as `limitfcn = @(fun,a)(fun(a+eps) + fun(a-eps))/2` , Beware that when the limit is different on both sides its technically not defined but this function will still return you a value

Answer (score 1):

As far as I known, numerical computation of limits is little addressed in the litterature and in numerical packages. It is probably still more an art than a technology.

One of the possible reasons is that computation of limits does challenge numerical accuracy as it involves arbitrary large values or ones arbitrarily close to a given value, causing any kinds of overflows or trunction errors and other pathologies. So a direct attack is often infeasible.

In some cases, special functions are available to work around unstable computations. For instance, the function `e^x-1` is readily available in Matlab as `expm1`, and the limit of `expm1(x) / x` can lead to a much better estimate than `(exp(x) - 1) / x`.

The Taylor approximations can often be helpful, but good solutions will often require some amount of symbolic computation. With the given case, one would establish that `(e^x - 1) / x ~ 1 + x/2 + x²/6 + x³/24...` after simplification.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *cannot*  calculate `fun(0)`, since that's a limit point, so obviously MATLAB will give you a `NaN` value. You need to *approach*  `x=0` to get infinitely close to `1`, but you can't actually *get* there. That's maths for you. What you can do is create a function like

```
function result = fun(x)

result = (1-exp(-x))./x;
result(x==0)=1; % remove the singularity if present
```

Comment: So the only way I can do is to write another function. There does not exist any built-in function to obtain the limit, if the function is defined as annoymous function.

Comment: Not sure. The problem is that the function does not exist in the limit point, hence it obviously won't work. You can't use an anonymous function to calculate multiline equations such as this, so you need a full function. There is a function called [`limit`](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/limit.html) which calculates limit points, but that requires a symbolic input and is as such very slow.